# Gradle version flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

Hi how I can change the gradle version of my flutter project ?

Because i accidentally updated gradle from android studio and it causes multiple error.

( I'm on windows 10)

Edit: I finally succeeded thanks to your answers for those who want I modified the gradle.properties file and change the line corresponding to the verion

Comment: there is a file called gradle.properties
you can specify gradle version there.

Comment: See this link [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49438)